# List Output to array using one variable from class

Tags: c#, asp.net, list

I am playing with lists to better understand them. Can I output a specific class variable to a List selection to compact the following code?

Here is what I think should be possible
**(DB.OperationsTeam.(choose just the UserEmail variable from POPSUser class))**

```
private string OperationsMembers
{
    get
    {
        List<POPSUser> UniqueList = DB.OperationsTeam.UserEmail.Distinct().ToList();
        return string.Join(";", UniqueList);
    }
}
```

Expected output: adam@my.domain; carol@my.domain; bill@my.domain

Here is current working code, but don't think I need to create another List and loop with a foreach. I used Distinct() because some users would be in multiple departments within the database query.

```
private string OperationsMembers
{
    get
    {
        List<string> EmailAddressList = new List<string>();

        foreach (POPSUser user in DB.OperationsTeam)
        {
            EmailAddressList.Add(user.UserEmail);
        }

        if (EmailAddressList.Count > 0)
        {
            List<string> UniqueList = EmailAddressList.Distinct().ToList();
            return string.Join(";", UniqueList);
        }
        else { return ""; }
    }
}
```

DB.OperationsTeam is a POPSUser List with UserID, UserName, UserEmail etc.

** UPDATE AFTER HELPFUL COMMENTS (didn't know where else to post helpful answer) ***
Nice, clean, and compact, thanks all!

```
private string OperationsMembers
{
    get
    {
        return string.Join(";", DB.OperationsTeam.Select(u => u.UserEmail).Distinct());
    }
}
```

Comment: BTWm you don't need `ToList()`.

Comment: Which version of .NET are you using?

Comment: Asp.net v4.0. Sorry about title, I type the title hoping to view results of already asked questions. Then when down on the tagging section I don't remember the title. So don't leave what i've tagged in title?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should project your `POPSUser` entity to email string. Use [Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548743%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) operator for projection:

```
DB.OperationsTeam.Select(u => u.UserEmail).Distinct();
```

Side note: your current working solution will load whole user data from database (i.e. name, email, id, etc) and instantiate user instances when you will enumerate over OperationsTeam set. But when you do projection as above, it will occur on server side and that will generate SQL which loads only required fields:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   [Extent1].[UserEmail] AS [UserEmail]
FROM [dbo].[OperationsTeam] AS [Extent1]
```

Comment: perfect! Thanks for the comment and all of your clarification revisions ;)

Comment: @AdamRoof welcome :) I also added comment which shows big difference between this solution and your current solution. And as Stanley pointed, you don't need to create list.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `.Distinct()` will return "distinct" `POPSUser` instances which may not be what you want.  If you want distinct *emails*, just insert a `Select` to extract the email value:

```
var UniqueList = DB.OperationsTeam
                   .Select(u => u.UserEmail)
                   .Distinct()
                   .ToList();

return string.Join(";", UniqueList);
```

Also note that `ToList` is not necessary since `string.Join` will accept an `IEnumerable<string>`.

Comment: Thanks for the ToList comment, just went down to one line!

Comment: ...and yes the problem you identified in the first sentence is exactly what was happening and I was playing with options after the Distinct, but should have been playing with the OperationsTeam results. The clarification is great, thanks again.